# how to scroll layout in appium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, android

I have below code :

```
MobileElement mb = (MobileElement)configuration.driver.findElement(By.className("android.widget.ScrollView"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)configuration.driver;
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<>();
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
scrollObject.put("element", ((MobileElement) mb).getId());
scrollObject.put("text", "Proceed");
        js.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", scrollObject);
```

But I'm getting exception

> Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

I am using **Java-client-5.0.0**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending many hours I got the working answer. In my case I have scrollview and I want to scroll screen to last button (Proceed).

```
String str = "Proceed";
            configuration.driver
                    .findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\""+ str + "\").instance(0))");
```

str is text which is written on the button.

Comment: This solution is working perfect. But I am working with Android date picker, On year listview  scrolling is not working properly. Always scrolling up and down. Please help me to solve this?  Note: In date picker year list view is inside scrollview, is this root cause?

Comment: It's for scrolling for a button which has text (Proceed). I want to scroll screen to last element which is a Logo and has no text. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WebElement fromElement=driver.findElement(By.id("locator"));
WebElement toElement= driver.findElement(By.id("locator"));
TouchAction tAction=new TouchAction(driver);
tAction.press(fromElement).moveTo(toElement).release().perform();
```

Comment: hi prasd thanx for the reply...but it is not working ...

Comment: ohh...but this got worked for me....

Comment: what did you put in locator ??????

Comment: can you tell me which libraries are you using ...?

Answer (score 0):

Driver.scrollTo (value) only working when android.widget.ListView have single text in it and it fails when multiple text is present in each row of listView. In my case I have single entry/text in each line.
So to resolve your issue you can use below method which I implemented for me and it is working fine.

```
**public WebElement scroll(String keyword) { HashMap scrollObject = new HashMap(); RemoteWebElement element = (RemoteWebElement)
    driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator( "new
    UiSelector().className(\"android.widget.ListView\")");
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; String
    webElementId = ((RemoteWebElement) element).getId();
    System.out.println(webElementId);System.out.println(element);
    scrollObject.put("text", keyword); scrollObject.put("element",
    webElementId); js.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", scrollObject);
    return element; }**
```

Comment: hi jensi....this solution not worked for me...its giving exception "Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)".

Comment: Ohh..,still not solved. Wait will share you another way.

Comment: okay jensi.....

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the first answer if it's not useful and use this one if it's useful for you.

```
WebElement list = driver.findElement(By.id("id of your list"));

         HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
         scrollObject.put("text", "name to search");
         scrollObject.put("element",( (RemoteWebElement) list).getId());
         driver.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", scrollObject);
         if(scrollObject.containsValue("string to search"))
         {
            System.out.println("Found");
            List<WebElement> list_user = list.findElements(By.id("id of the text view"));
            for (WebElement component : list_user) {
               System.out.println(component.getText());
               if (component.getText().contains("string to search")) {
                    component.click();
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not equal");
                }
         }
         }
         else
         {
             System.out.println("Not Found");
         }
```

Comment: hi jensi...ur solution is working for listview ...but I have ScrollView...

Comment: can you tell me which libraries are you using ...?